# Protected Android IDs in R.java

Tags: android, resources, r.java-file

For those of use who have spent any amount of time in the Android source code, it's not news that the IDs generated in the `android.R` class do not 1:1 reflect the actual resources found in the `res/` directories of the supplied JAR.  Many of the drawables/styles/layouts are not "public" and accessible to applications by referencing `android.R.xxx`.

My question is does anyone know the mechanism by which `Android` is able to generate an R.java class that differs from the actual resource graph?  Secondarily, is it a mechanism (using build rules, etc.) that we as developers could leverage to partially protect the ids that get made public in applications used as libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Android packages resources using aapt, and generates the R file using this tool during the build process. In this step, XML files are compiled to binary and other resources are just packaged as they are. You can open up a .apk file as a zip archive and access all the resource files as is. Library projects simply contain source files and resources that are added into the project at compile time, so they would exist somehow in the .apk file. Probably the layouts are not 1:1 because the XML is already compiled for the library project. There is probably a way you could use aapt to remove the files from the library project from being included at build time, but then they wouldn't be accessible in your project. There also might be a way to obfuscate your resource names at compile time using aapt and ant, but then that doesn't stop them from being able to access them.

I'm not sure why you would want to want an R.java class that differs from the actual resource graph. Either don't include those resources at build time or they are going to be in the apk. Your layouts are compressed as binary files in the output, so I'm not sure how easy they are to decompile or reuse in another project.

What is the endgame here? If it is to protect your resources, it will be hard. Android is extremely insecure if someone has the ability to root their phone. If you want to protect your IP, which I'm assuming is the endgame here, I would try and compile my project into an apk and see if I can decompile or extract the critical resources from the apk. Maybe try some obfuscation, but again, I don't know enough about the compiled XML files to know if they get obfuscated enough to not be easily decompiled.

Someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but this is just my 2 cents.

Comment: The primary goal of the question is simply to learn how the Android ROM build of R.java is able to exclude resources.  You have an interesting point about the layouts possible being compiled in two-steps, although this logic wouldn't work for the drawables that are excluded, so there must be another method at play.  With regards to the second question, security is not the concern as much as cleaning up the pollution that occurs in the final R.java file with library projects since all the ids end up combining into a single `R` class reference in the main package, often leading to overlaps.

Comment: @Devunwired Are you using proguard or an obsfucation tool? When I look through my apk files all my drawables (such as .png images) are simply located in the res folder in their respective spot. Again, like I said, the R.java file is created during the aapt step of the compilation phase, so if anything like what you want is possible, it will be before or during that step.

Comment: That's exactly my point, but do that exercise with android.jar instead of your own app.  You will notice that the `res/` directory has a lot more drawables than you will be able to reference by calling `android.R.drawable.xxx` in your code.

Comment: @Devunwired Good point, I was unaware of this fact. However, my last question to you is why would you want to have to files in the res folders but not be able to access them from code? I've come up with the problem of having unwanted resources in my res folders between different builds, but I ended up creating a simple script that manages that by simply removing the unwanted resources before the build and then adding them back in after.

Comment: Well, often resources in a library project are only important to the library and not the application that uses it.  It would be nice to not have these resource IDs cluttering up the using applications project.